# Have to map XML data into a SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, database, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm getting XML data in my stored procedure and want to update the corresponding SQL Server table by mapping the values.

This is a sample of the XML:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML = '<NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>India</SystemKey>
        <Translation>Bharat</Translation>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>UAE</SystemKey>
        <Translation>United Arab Emirates</Translation>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>Afghanistan</SystemKey>
        <Translation>Afghanistan</Translation>
      </Table>
      </NewDataSet>'
```

Code is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    t.c.value('(SystemKey/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [SystemKey],
    r.c.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Translation
FROM 
    @xmldata.nodes('NewDataSet/Table') AS t(c)
CROSS APPLY 
    t.c.nodes('*[local-name(.) != "SystemKey"]') AS r(c)
```

I want to update table 2 with the values from XML data; eg. SystemKey = Table2.KEY AND Translation = Table2.Translation.

Can I do this directly without a temp table and a cursor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after? (I wasn't sure what type of update you were trying to achieve. You could do the same with a merge if you want an insert or update).

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML = '<NewDataSet>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>India</SystemKey>
        <Translation>Bharat</Translation>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>UAE</SystemKey>
        <Translation>United Arab Emirates</Translation>
      </Table>
      <Table>
        <SystemKey>Afghanistan</SystemKey>
        <Translation>Afghanistan</Translation>
      </Table>
      </NewDataSet>';

WITH Translations
AS
(
    SELECT 
        t.c.value('(SystemKey/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [SystemKey],
        r.c.value('text()[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Translation
    FROM 
        @xmldata.nodes('NewDataSet/Table') AS t(c)
    CROSS APPLY 
        t.c.nodes('*[local-name(.) != "SystemKey"]') AS r(c)
)
UPDATE t2 
    SET t2.Translation = t.Translation 
FROM Table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN Translations AS t
ON t.SystemKey = t2.SystemKey;
```